# Registered COM interface fails to resolve when when using Lifestyle.Singleton

Tags: simple-injector

Inside our codebase, we consume a lot of COM objects from C#, few places instead of directly creating using the *Class generated by Interop, the ProgID was used to create those COM objects.

Previous code based on NInject used to work fine in this case but now it been decided to move on with SimpleInjector.

This can be easily reproduced with the following sample source code:
*[Reference added to C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll - “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” for sample of COM usage]*

```
   public class TextFileCreator
   {
      private FileSystemObject _fso;
      public TextFileCreator(FileSystemObject fso)
      {
         _fso = fso;
      }

      public void Do()
      {
         string filename = _fso.GetTempName();
         var tf = _fso.CreateTextFile(filename);
         tf.WriteLine("Hello World");
         tf.Close();
      }
   }

   public class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Container container = new Container();
         container.Register<TextFileCreator>();
         container.Register(typeof(FileSystemObject), () => {
            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            FileSystemObject fso = (FileSystemObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return fso;
         }, Lifestyle.Singleton);

         TextFileCreator textFileCreator = container.GetInstance<TextFileCreator>();
         textFileCreator.Do();
      }

      static void MainOriginal(string[] args)
      {
         Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
         FileSystemObject fso = (FileSystemObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
         TextFileCreator textFileCreator = new TextFileCreator(fso);
         textFileCreator.Do();
      }
   }
```

SimpleInjector registration with `Lifestyle.Singleton`:

```
container.Register(typeof(FileSystemObject), () => {
            Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            FileSystemObject fso = (FileSystemObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return fso;
         }, Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Is generating the following exception

> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: 'The configuration is invalid.
> Creating the instance for type TextFileCreator failed. Expression of
> type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be used for constructor parameter of
> type 'Scripting.FileSystemObject' Verification was triggered because
> Container.Options.EnableAutoVerification was enabled. To prevent the
> container from being verified on first resolve, set
> Container.Options.EnableAutoVerification to false.'

But it is working if Lifestyle.Singleton is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Injector v5 added support for resolving COM objects, but solely when they are registered using the`RegisterInstance` method.

Comment: Thanks Steven. But now even with `Register` it works if `Lifestyle.Transient` is used

Comment: It Transient works, that's rather by accident, not by design.